# Compiling with icpc - using libraries

Tags: c++, icc

I'm trying to compile a code that #includes the library

In the code I have the following lines:

```
int main()
{
    clock_t begin = clock();
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 gen(rd());
    uniform_real_distribution<> U(0,1);
    default_random_engine generator;
    rr1=U(gen); 
}
```

When I compile using the following line:

```
 icpc  -std=c++0x -std=c++11 -o main main.cpp -O3
```

I get the following errors:

> main.cpp(152): error: identifier "uniform_real_distribution" is undefined
>           uniform_real_distribution<> U(0,1);
>           ^
>
> main.cpp(152): error: expected an expression
>           uniform_real_distribution<> U(0,1);
>                                     ^
>
> main.cpp(368): error: identifier "default_random_engine" is undefined
>           default_random_engine generator;
>           ^
>
> main.cpp(441): error: identifier "U" is undefined
>                   rr1=U(gen); // first random number for time interval
>
> main.cpp(509): warning #1595: non-POD (Plain Old Data) class type
>   passed through ellipsis
>                           rr1=U(gen);

any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Try `std::uniform_real_distribution` and try use the appropriate version of `icpc`. ref. https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/474159

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by your Intel's compiler icpc version does not completely support c++11, which is actually c++0x.

That means:

- You need to update your Intel's compiler to support `uniform_real_distribution`.
- Or using some library such as [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_random.html), [PCG](http://www.pcg-random.org/), etc.
- Or still using c++11 way but without uniform_real_distribution. For example directly use `mt19937` , `mt19937_64` or any other pseudo-random generator.
- Or using non-c++11 way i.e. rand() or rand_r() for nonserious use.

I guess the above part answered your question.

---

*Want to Know More?*

For Intel's user, you can check the compiler's compatibility by first and translate icc's version number into to a relative same gcc's version number and then check from [c++0x/c++11 supported list](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11)

For GNU's user, you can check the compiler's compatibility directly from [c++0x/c++11 supported list](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11)

for example, you can

`$icpc -v`

You may get something like

`icpc version a.b.c (gcc version x.y.z compatibility)`

That means your Inter compiler's version is a.b.c and its compatibility is as gcc version x.y.z.

And since `uniform_real_distribution` is **not** supported till [GCC 4.4.5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html)? (GCC 4.4.7 is verified support)

Then if your x.y.z is later than 4.4.5?(4.4.7 for sure) you can use 'uniform_xxx_distribution' function families without compatibility issues.